# $\mathcal N (A):=\mathcal P(A)\setminus\{\varnothing\}$ notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, terminology

Define $\mathcal N$

$\mathcal N (A):=\mathcal P(A)\setminus\{\varnothing\}$

Does $\mathcal N$ has a special name and standard notation?

Comment: Do you mean $\mathcal P(A)\setminus\{\varnothing\}$ maybe? As written $\mathcal N(A)=\mathcal P(A)$.

Comment: Yes. Thats what i meant,  you can edit my question id you want. @Asaf Karagila

Comment: You should do that. It's your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading wikipedia I found this interesting notation. The nice thing is that its seems to be a natural choiche even if wikipedia does not give references for this.

> The set of subsets of $S$ of cardinality less than $\kappa$ is denoted by $\mathcal{P}_{\kappa}(S)$ or $\mathcal{P}_{<\kappa}(S) $,
>
> Similarly, the set of non-empty subsets of $S$ might be denoted by
>   $\mathcal{P}_{\geq 1}(S)$ .

[Powerset at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set)

Comment: I don't have a reference at hand but I can confirm that I've seen this usage in several books.  Most people will probably understand it without further explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no particular name. However, you can introduce your set as follows:

$$\mathcal P_0 (A):=\mathcal P(A) \setminus\{\varnothing\}$$

recalling that, mutatis mutandis, often $\mathbb{N}_0$ is used in place of $\mathbb{N}$ when one wants to represent the natural number without the $0$:

$$\mathbb{N}_0 = \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$$

or to impose that $0$ is inside the set:

$$\mathbb{N} = \mathbb{N}_0 \cup \{0\}$$

Comment: Usually, people who exclude $0$ prom $\Bbb N$ write $\Bbb N_0$ to mean they're including it, or just to tell they mean the natural numbers with the zero. I would denote $\Bbb N\smallsetminus \{0\}$ by $\Bbb N_{>0}$, instead.

Comment: I agree with you. For me $0$ is not a natural number, but in my experience I read a lot of papers/books in which $\mathbb{N}_0$ is used to exclude the $0$ as far as $\mathbb{N}_+$ or $\mathbb{N}_{>0}$

Comment: I would denote that as $\Bbb Z^+$...

Comment: @the_candyman: Note it's $\mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$ instead of $\mathbb{N} \setminus 0$ and likewise for the $\cup$ case.